# How to perform binomial logistic regression on this dataset?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
     id quantity effect
1     1 0.00        3
2     1 0.00        1
3     1 1.50        1
4     1 0.00        1
5     1 0.00        1
6     1 0.00        2
7     1 0.00        1
8     1 0.00        1
9     2 4.00        2
10    2 0.00        1
```

To explain this dataset, we are evaluating the effect of a potential medicine on rats.

**Quantity** column has 3 categories **(0.00, 1.5, 4 g/kg)**.

**Effect**  column has 3 categories : **1** = alive, **2** = sick,  **3** =dead

I would like to perform a binary model in order to indicate the developmental effects of this medicine by doing **Alive** rats VS (**Sick** and **Dead**).

I created a new column called **is.alive** that had rows following this rule:

```
mydata$is.alive=1
mydata$is.alive[mydata$effect!="1"] = 0

     quantity effect is.alive
    0        3         0
    0        1         1
    0        1         1
    0        1         1
    0        1         1
    0        1         1
```

Afterwards I fit a glm using **is.alive** as my response:

```
mymodel=glm(data$is.alive~data$quantity,data=mydata,family="binomial")
summary(mymodel)
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    2.71412    0.15346   17.69   <2e-16 ***
 mydata$quantity -1.10154    0.07616  -14.46   <2e-16 ***
```

But this is not what I'm looking for, I'm trying to examine the developmental effect of this medicine by fitting a model that takes dose as response for an **alive**  VS a **dead** or **sick**.

For some reason I don't have 2 parameters for the **Quantity* covariate although it is categorical.. I also am not sure whether I did the right thing... I can't understand the summary of this model.

Why don't I have the parameter estimates for each **Quantity** categories?

I'm new to R and logistic regression so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to declare your quantity as a factor (e.g. factor() or as.factor() depending on your needs), so your model thinks it is continuous.

Comment: You seem very confused about which variable to put on the left and right hand side of the equation. You state what you did and then state you wanted to do the reverse. Your statement of your scientific question agrees with one of them which is good. You also seem to have multiple measurement per rat which requires a more complex model. It is hard to know what advice to give now except to employ a statistician locally to analyse the data for you

Answer (score 1):

Your independent variable is treated as a numeric variable in the analyses. If you want to get estimates for each of the levels of a categorical independent variable (vs. the reference level), you need to make sure that the variable is recognized as a factor. This means that the variable should have a 'factor' format. To check if this the case, you can use the function 'is.factor()'. You can change the format from numeric to factor using the 'as.factor()' function.